# angular material chips field to make a chip from remaining entered text

Tags: javascript, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am using angular material `md-chips` field. The chips are currently formed only after I hit one of the the `md-seperator-keys`.

But when the focus is out of the chips filed, the remaining entered text must automatically form a chip. How to achieve this?

```
<md-chips monitor-input-focus ng-model="formData[fieldDef.identifier]"
          md-separator-keys="chipKeys"
          name="inputField"
          style="margin-bottom:8px;">
      <md-chip-template>
          {{$chip}}
      </md-chip-template>
</md-chips>
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/angular/material/issues/3364

Comment: Yeah, I followed that post and got my problem fixed with the help of some posts put up like 15 days ago. Thanks @nitin

Answer (score -1):

Try the `md-chips` attribute and the `md-add-on-blur` for creating this behaviour.

See here: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips